# POST request in webclient to add a request body in JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, arraylist, spring-webclient

I am trying to make API POST Request with WebClient in Spring Boot. But I cannot make a request with JSON body as I want and receive response as JSONObject.

JSON BODY :

```
{
"workspaces": [
"6eret123",
"b129078v",
"ngy66553",
"erfc1153"
]
}
```

Service class-

```
Workspaces workspace = new Workspaces(mw);
Flux<Workspaces> modifiedWorkspace = webClient.post().uri(URIDetails.MODIFIEDWORKSPACE)
.header("Authorization", bearerToken).body(Mono.just(mw), Workspaces.class).retrieve()
.bodyToFlux(Workspaces.class);
modifiedWorkspace.doOnNext(System.out::println).blockLast();
return null;
```

Workspaces model-

```
public class Workspaces {
private List<String> workspaces;
}
```

Main call-

```
Flux<ScanIDModel> modifiedWorkspaces;
final List<String> mw = new ArrayList<>();
for (Workspace w : modifiedWorkspaces) {
mw.add(w.getId());
}
modifiedWorkspaces = scanRespone(mw);
```

I need to send a list of JSON body mentioned as a body post request.
Please help me to do the post request
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;


public class Testclass{

@Autowired
private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;//webclient builder instance

public void testMethod(){

Class<Object> cls = Object.class;//object class of the request body
//Object obj is also the object of the request body
Object obj = webClientBuilder.build().post().uri("{{url}}")
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header("Authorization", "{{authtoken}}")
                    .bodyValue(user).retrieve().bodyToMono(clazz).block();
}
}
```

hope something on it might help.

Comment: and its getting truncated, how to frame it above JSON body

Comment: I am getting a request body in the form of this
[Workspaces(workspaces=[6eret123,b129078v,ngy66553,erfc1153...truncated]]